# Why do we need to quotient out by the normal subgroup in Van-Kampen's theorem?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I've found few different formulations for Van-Kampen's theorem the first of which states that if $X = A \cup B$ where $A$ and $B$ are path-connected, contain the basepoint $x_0$ and $A \cap B$ is path-connected then $$\pi_1(X) \cong \pi_1(A) \ast \pi_1(B)/N$$ where $N$ is the smallest normal subgroup of $\pi_1(A) \ast \pi_1(B)$ with the identification $\iota_1([\gamma])=\iota_2([\gamma])$ for $\gamma \in A \cap B$ and $\iota_1: \pi_1(A \cap B) \to \pi_1(A), \iota_2:\pi(A \cap B) \to \pi_1(B)$.

The second one is done with amalgamation which is essentially the same thing, but they just denote $\pi_1(X) \cong \pi_1(A) \ast \pi_1(B)/N$ as $\pi_1(X) \cong \pi_1(A) \ast_{\pi(A \cap B)} \pi_1(B)$.

**My question is why do we need this normal subgroup $N$ here at all? And why do we require it to be the smallest one?** I see that we want to identify the loops in $\pi_1(A \cap B)$ which are sent by the inclusions $\iota_1$ and $\iota_2$ to $\pi_1(A)$ and $\pi_1(B)$, but why do we want to do this kind of thing?

Comment: It's easy to see that the result is not true without some quotient—consider $A=B$ for example.

Comment: Try looking at the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me steal this diagram from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert%E2%80%93Van_Kampen_theorem):

[image]

It's clear that:

- $\pi_{1}(U_1 \cap U_2)$ maps to $\pi_{1}(U_1)$ and $\pi_{1}(U_2)$. This is the map on homotopy induced by inclusion.
- $\pi_{1}(U_1)$ and $\pi_{1}(U_2)$ map to $\pi_{1}(X)$. This is also given by inclusion.

It's not hard to see:

- Every element of $\pi_{1}(X)$ can be factored into a product of elements in $\pi_{1}(U_1)$ and $\pi_{1}(U_2)$. This is a standard homework exercise in a first topology course.
- As a result, there is a surjection from $\pi_{1}(U_1) \ast \pi_{1}(U_2)$ to $\pi_{1}(X)$.
- However, this surjection will generally not be injective. Suppose that there is a nontrivial element $\gamma \in \pi_{1}(U_1 \cap U_2)$ that remains nontrivial when mapped to $\pi_{1}(X)$. Then the two, distinct nontrivial elements $i_{1}(\gamma) \ast 1$ and $1 \ast i_{2}(\gamma)$ in $\pi_{1}(U_1) \ast \pi_{1}(U_2)$ map to the same element of $\pi_{1}(X)$.
- To fix this, we can identify all pairs of the form $i_{1}(\gamma) \ast 1$ and $1 \ast i_{2}(\gamma)$.
- In the language of group theory, if you want to make such identifications, you introduce the relators $(i_{1}(\gamma) \ast 1)^{-1}(1 \ast i_{2}(\gamma))$.
- Adding group relations is the same thing as quotienting out by smallest normal subgroup (the *normal closure*) containing the relators.

The remaining work to be done:

- We can see that there is a surjection from the amalgamated product to $\pi_{1}(X)$. But it is injective (and hence a homeomorphism)? In other words, has our amalgamation trick taken care of all possible failures of injectivity? Working this out completes the proof, and is a more difficult.

Comment: In the first bullet on "It's not hard to see" what do you mean by factoring into a product? Since $X = U_1 \cup U_2$ do we have some way to use the product of $U_1$ and $U_2$?

Comment: Not the product of the the sets, the product of the fundamental groups. Think of the simple case when $U_1 \cap U_2$ is just a point $\{p\}$. Then any loop in $X$ starting at $p$ moves around in $U_1$, then passes through $p$ and winds around in $U_2$ for a bit, then hits $p$ again and moves into $U_1$, etc. Thus the whole loop is a product of loops, each of which is entirely in $U_1$ or $U_2$.